# Classic ASP - Pull URL from String

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Trying to only pull the URL between two quotes in a text string.  I want to end with "www.youtube.com/embed/abcdefg"  Currently, EndURL pulls a 0 which means it didn't find a double quote.

```
Link_Youtube = <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/abcdefg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

StartURL =  Instr(Link_Youtube,"src=")
EndURL =    Instr(startURL+7, Link_Youtube, Instr(Link_Youtube,""""))
Link_Youtube = Mid(Link_Youtube, startURL+6, EndURL)
```

---

**Updated (working) Code:**

```
If Instr(Link_Youtube,"iframe") > 0 Then    'embed
    startURL =  Instr(Link_Youtube,"src=")+7
    EndURL =    Instr(startURL, Link_Youtube, """") - startURL
    Link_Youtube = Mid(Link_Youtube, startURL, EndURL)
End If
```

Comment: Shouldn't this line be: `EndURL =    Instr(startURL+7, Link_Youtube, """")`

Comment: Good suggestion as that's the path I ended up going down as well.  Go figure, i beat my head against the wall until I post here then figured it out 10 minutes later, lol.

Comment: chr(34) is the double quote and can be used with Instr